# How to change text with document.write and delete past text

Tags: javascript, text, loading

I want to make a loading animation for a website, and I thought that these Unicode characters would look good:☰ ☱ ☲ ☴ but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How you're ever going to do this, don't use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) in the implementation, it is just not purposed for tasks like you've at hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with something like this:

```js
var animationContainer = document.querySelector('#animation');
var animationThing = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  switch (animationThing) {
    case 0:
        animationContainer.innerHTML = '☰';
        animationThing++;
        break;
        
    case 1:
        animationContainer.innerHTML = '☱';
        animationThing++;
        break;
        
    case 2:
        animationContainer.innerHTML = '☲';
        animationThing++;
        break;
        
    case 3:
        animationContainer.innerHTML = '☴';
        animationThing = 0;
        break;
   }
}, 200);
```

```html
<span id="animation"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of methods for setting the content of an element. It's just a case of using either `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to keep changing the content after a pause.

For example:

```js
const chars = ['☰','☱', '☲', '☴'];
const el = document.getElementById('spinner');

let index = 0;

function changeChar() {
  el.innerText = chars[index];
  index = (index + 1) % chars.length;
  setTimeout(changeChar, 200);
}

changeChar()
```

```html
<div id="spinner" />
```